# Edit List Box Data

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there anyway you can allow the user to edit existing data in a List Box  ? For example the user can just click the cell then type in what they want ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For that functionality, I would suggest using a LISTVIEW control.  There are hooks in it (`LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT`, `LVN_ENDLABELEDIT`) to allow you to do what your want.

Comment: Note that the ListView control only allows you to edit the label (column 0), not any other columns.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You can get access to the window of the built-in editor using [`LVM_GETEDITCONTROL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774919.aspx). With a little extra work, you can manipulate it to edit columns other than 0.